# Is there a better way to change the values of a Series?

Tags: python, pandas, series

I am a newbie at Python and Pandas and I was if there is a better way to replace the values in a Series.  Here is the code that I have:

```
import pandas as pd
rank = pd.Series(data=[161.140890, 146.989804, 133.589100, 131.220764, 124.506911],
                 index=['SB', 'EKDKQ', 'APD', 'DIS', 'MDR'])
print(rank)
```

This is my output:

```
SB       161.140890
EKDKQ    146.989804
APD      133.589100
DIS      131.220764
MDR      124.506911
dtype: float64
```

I would like to replace the values with a sequence number like 1,2,3.....
I can it with this code:

```
x = 1
for i, v in rank.items():
    rank.loc[i] = x
    x += 1
print(rank)
```

and I get:

```
SB       1.0
EKDKQ    2.0
APD      3.0
DIS      4.0
MDR      5.0
dtype: float64
```

which is fine but it doesn't look like 'Pandas' code.  My code looks more like C++. Can the pandas experts out there show me how to do it the pandas way?

Comment: what do you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

Better use [`range`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range)/[`numpy.arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html) and assign directly:

```
rank[:] = range(1, rank.size+1)

# or
rank[:] = np.arange(1, rank.size+1)
```

Output:

```
SB       1.0
EKDKQ    2.0
APD      3.0
DIS      4.0
MDR      5.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

```
(rank.reset_index().drop(columns=[0]).reset_index().set_index("index")+1).rename(columns={"level_0":"rank"})["rank"]

#
index
SB       1
EKDKQ    2
APD      3
DIS      4
MDR      5
Name: rank, dtype: int64
```

Creativity is key :)